# Where does R Yitzchak Abadi's understanding of kashrus differ from mainstream kashrus organizations?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

In [a previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138347/can-kashrus-be-judged-by-ingredients-lists?noredirect=1#comment462320_138347) I asked about when one can use ingredients lists to determine kashrus. Now, I'd like to ask how specifically does R Yitzchak Abadi's understanding of kashrus differ from the mainstream that he/his followers determine kashrus of products based on ingredients lists without a hechsher or knowledge of the practices of the specific manufacturer (eg [here](https://learn.oheltorah.com/t/trader-joe-s-ramen/22586), where eg the manufacturer of Trader Joes brand products is a trade secret.)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to ask him?

Comment: "determine kashrus of products based on ingredients lists without a hechsher or knowledge of the practices of the specific manufacturer" As noted there, everyone does this for sufficiently simple products and no one does it for sufficiently complex products. The question is just which issues you are looking for and hence which items are "simple" vs "complex".

Comment: @rosends I wouldn't have thought he would be available for questions like that, let me know if you think otherwise

Comment: @DoubleAA If that is the basis of the difference, I'm still curious if there are specific sevaras that the machlochus is going on that would cause someone to come out differently on that question, and if anyone has more info. He's published shalas vtehuvos and has followers, so maybe it is discussed somewhere specifically.

Comment: Hi @ak0000 I am glad you're here trying to expand your knowledge base. In my opinion, the scope of this question appears to be either a duplicate, or too open-ended to practically answer here. If your question is once again about how R. Abadi can rely on ingredients alone, without particular knowledge of the manufacturer it is the former. And if you are asking open-endedly about where he may or may not differ with the mainstream on a topic as vast as "kashruth" - then it is the latter. Can you edit to reflect these concerns?

Comment: [Ohr Yishaq vol. 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/1525) and [Ohr Yishaq vol. 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/54963)

Comment: @Deuteronomy Hi there, maybe I'll try to clarify here and you can let me know what you think. What I was hoping for was a 3-5 sentence answer that describes what specific source or halachic principle is the crux of the dispute, explaining why R Abadi holds as he does. It didn't seem like a duplicate to me because the previous question was about using ingredients generally and attracted generic answers about the question, but I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with what specific sources he is learning differently that he comes out so differently l'maisa.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Maybe there are too many such sources or differences to summarize, but it seems sometimes differences in psak can originate from a very small number of differences in approach to sources/halachic principles, and I didn't think it was unreasonable to see if anyone had a succinct answer. I appreciate the link to the sefarim but until I have a chance to work through them I'm curious if anyone is familiar with his approach, he taught an entire generation of poskim in lakewood so it didn't seem so unlikely someone might know.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Also (based on discussions with those that rely with R. Abadi) I believe that he would argue that his general position was historically the default position. It is the mainstream that has drifted towards stringency on this topic. A consequence of both a general rightwards trend religiously/socially and the rise of modern commodified kashruth certification.

Comment: Interesting! In which case someone might be able to answer conversely which particular sources/principles the mainstream became cholek on him regarding, if there are specific ones as opposed to a general shift in practice. Thanks for your help!